# Scripts not found at relative locations

Tags: gradle

I have a structure which looks something like this:

```
proj/myserver/build.gradle
common/common.gradle
common/server.gradle
```

build.gradle needs to
`apply from: '../../common/server.gradle'`
and server.gradle needs to `apply from:'common.grade`.

This second apply does not work however as `server.gradle` is looking for `common.gradle` in a location relative to `build.gradle`...

How do I get all the relative paths correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paths are always resolved relative to the project directory, not the script plugin that is calling `apply`. In this case you would have to do something like

```
apply from: "$projectDir/../../common/common.gradle"
```

This however might cause problems with multi-project builds (in which case you should use `rootDir` or other projects whose relative path might differ slightly. In that case you might want to set a project property indicating the location of  the 'common' folder.

**build.gradle**

```
ext {
    commonDir = file("$projectDir/../../common")
}
```

**server.gradle**

```
apply from: "$commonDir/common.gradle"
```